# YouTube API - Direct. Is there a way to limit embed code accessibility to only certain users?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Utilising YouTube Direct so that users can upload video's for approval directly to my site.

1) All the approved videos will be displayed in some form of gallery on the site.

2) All registered users will be able to view thus galleries.

**My Question:**

> Is there a way to limit or restrict access to the actual embed code of those playlist/ gallery video on my site?
>
> We would like to make it so that all users can view all videos on the site but a (business users - who wants to embed a video on their own site) they must have access rights supplied by our company first.

In basic form. If a business user wants to use/ embed a piece of video content which has been generated through our site to use on that companies own site - they must be a paying subscriber.

> Therefore is there a way of limiting access of the embed code to certain users?

Appreciate any help. :)

Answer (score 0):

YouTube videos can be public, unlisted, or private. There's a [discussion of private and unlisted videos](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=157177) in the general YouTube help center.

There's nothing specific in the API that gives you access to other options beyond what YouTube supports.